# I bought Astroneer on Xbox, which has Xbox Play Anywhere enabled. Can I play with people on my PC who bought it via Steam?

Tags: steam, xbox-one, astroneer

I just picked up Astroneer for Xbox One. According to the store page, it is also an [Xbox Play Anywhere](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/games/xbox-play-anywhere) game, meaning I can download the game on my PC and play it on there as well.

If one of my other friends who doesn't have an Xbox buys it on Steam, can I play with them on my PC version also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Steam version will not support cross-play.

Your friend has to buy the game from the Windows store. I have it, but I'm not able to play with my friends on Xbox.

Comment: I can't really tell from your answer, but are you saying that you can't play your Windows Store PC version with people who bought it on Steam? It sounds more like you are saying Steam players can't play with Xbox players, which I expected.

Comment: @TimmyJim I think you're misreading “will not support crossplay” as “will not support multiplayer”. Crossplay means across different platforms.

Comment: Augh ignore my edit summary. The autofill messes everything up.

Comment: Astroneer Multiplayer is based on your friends list.  You can't add your friend on Steam on your Xbox/xbox application on Windows 10.  You can add your Xbox live friend on Windows 10.  This comment is based on the blog post for the game....